# What is gpg2 algo 1 and 8 concerning its signature-procedure?

Tags: rsa, signature, algorithm-design

While signing a test-file, gpg2 creates a file test.sig which contains this:

```
$ gpg2 --list-packets --verbose < test.sig
# off=0 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=540
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid C109A1FD84E2C2E5
    version 4, created 1510595093, md5len 0, sigclass 0x00
    digest algo 8, begin of digest cd 94
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2017-11-13)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID C109A1FD84E2C2E5)
    data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
```

I assume that algo 1 means RSA, but how can that be used to create `data` (which I suppose should be the signature) ? What is algo 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I assume that algo 1 means RSA

Correct. From [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-9.1):

```
9.1.  Public-Key Algorithms

      ID           Algorithm
      --           ---------
      1          - RSA (Encrypt or Sign) [HAC]
      2          - RSA Encrypt-Only [HAC]
      3          - RSA Sign-Only [HAC]
      16         - Elgamal (Encrypt-Only) [ELGAMAL] [HAC]
      17         - DSA (Digital Signature Algorithm) [FIPS186] [HAC]
      18         - Reserved for Elliptic Curve
      19         - Reserved for ECDSA
      20         - Reserved (formerly Elgamal Encrypt or Sign)
      21         - Reserved for Diffie-Hellman (X9.42,
                   as defined for IETF-S/MIME)
      100 to 110 - Private/Experimental algorithm
```

> What is algo 8?

It indicates that SHA-256 was used for computing the hash. Again, [from the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-9.4):

```
9.4.  Hash Algorithms

      ID           Algorithm                             Text Name
      --           ---------                             ---------
      1          - MD5 [HAC]                             "MD5"
      2          - SHA-1 [FIPS180]                       "SHA1"
      3          - RIPE-MD/160 [HAC]                     "RIPEMD160"
      4          - Reserved
      5          - Reserved
      6          - Reserved
      7          - Reserved
      8          - SHA256 [FIPS180]                      "SHA256"
      9          - SHA384 [FIPS180]                      "SHA384"
      10         - SHA512 [FIPS180]                      "SHA512"
      11         - SHA224 [FIPS180]                      "SHA224"
      100 to 110 - Private/Experimental algorithm
```

---

You might want to try to get some practice in reading RFCs. It can be a bit overwhelming at first, but the information is all there - especially for the OpenPGP standard which is extensively documented.